# How to create a entry chip fill in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, material-design

In the fill I want to Search from a String Adapter. A filterable list will be displayed. When I click submit I want all chip value on a String Array.

Comment: Can you provide some example?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add a Chip Group to root layout.

Step 2:

```
ChipGroup chipGroup = findViewById(R.id.chipGroup);
Chip chip = new Chip(this); //your newly created chip
chipGroup.addView(chip);
```

Comment: you can also add spacing to your ChipGroup.

Comment: Set text for your newly created chip by using setText.